# Sending 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors

Getting this error, what does it mean here.

```
[mediaPlayTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", [self formatTime:currentTime],[self formatTime:duration]]];

- (NSString*)formatTime:(float)time{
int minutes = time / 60;
int seconds = (int)time % 60;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d:%@%d", minutes / 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minutes / 10] : @"", minutes % 10, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", seconds / 10], seconds % 10];
}
```

Comment: It means something wants a reference to an object and you're giving it a 'double' instead.  What are the definitions of your methods and variables?

Comment: There's nothing in what you've shown that will cause that error.  What does the code before and after `setText:` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .h

```
  -(NSString*)formatTime:(float)time;
```

.m

```
  [mediaPlayTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", [self formatTime:currentTime],[self formatTime:duration]]];



 - (NSString*)formatTime:(float)time{
int minutes = time / 60;
int seconds = (int)time % 60;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d:%@%d", minutes / 10 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minutes / 10] : @"", minutes % 10, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", seconds / 10], seconds % 10];
}
```

just the minor changes solved the problem.